# htaccess redirect to a directory

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I'm facing a htaccess poroblem which I can't figure it out by myself.

Let's say I want to host two websites under the same hosting plan. The main website is a Prestashop eCommerce website. The other is a placeholder for another domain name.

For example, there is the main **[www.myshopdomain.com](http://www.myshopdomain.com)** in the root and **[www.myutilitydomain.com](http://www.myutilitydomain.com)** in a directory called *Utility*.

Currently, all traffic to **[www.myutilitydomain.com](http://www.myutilitydomain.com)** is redirected to **[www.myshopdomain.com](http://www.myshopdomain.com)**. What should I do to redirect all traffic for **[www.myutilitydomain.com](http://www.myutilitydomain.com)** to the *Utility* directory, preferably without any reference to **[www.myshopdomain.com](http://www.myshopdomain.com)** in the redirected URL? Is it even possible? I know I can create a subdomain, but I need the myutility domain to be accessible directly.

I tried a few approaches and managed not to break the eCommerce site, but for **[www.myutilitydomain.com](http://www.myutilitydomain.com)** I always get Internal Server Error.

My final attempt was this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myutilitydomain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^www.myutilitydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Utility/
```

Comment: Well, you define the "Utility" folder as the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` for a new virtual host inside your http server.

Comment: Hi, arkasha! I wish that mean something to me. All I can do is trial and error approach and it works in most cases, just not with htaccess. I really need a working code or a step by step explanation.

Comment: Or you take a look into the documentation...

Comment: Sorry, don't get the last comment wrong. I am not trying to make fun here. But if you operate a http server then surely it does make sense that you know the basics of how to configure it, right? And surely the best way to find out about specific details is to take a look into the documentation, right?

Comment: Right, but I don't operate the server. It is a managed server and all I do is upload my stuff and do python/php/html as I need. I struggled all night reading through tons of examples and explanations, but I don't quite understand how it works to make it work for me. All my attempts either broke the main eCommerce domain or didn't redirect at all, hence, I'm asking any good soul who knows how to do this for help.

Comment: Ah, so you do not have access to the server configuration. But you must have some form of configuration option, I assume. There is no possibility to map a host name to a folder? That is what I remember from the times when I still used a hosting provider...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RewriteCondition` is not right.
You can only match against `URL path` in a `%{REQUEST_URI}` RewriteCond not the host header.

Change it to

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Utility [NC]
```

Comment: Hi, Amit! Thanks for your answer, but it didn't work. I can see it briefly redirect to www.myutilitydomain.com but then it goes back to the eCommerce main domain.

Comment: @madaload then perhaps there is something else that redirects it to the other domain. Try clearing your browser cache to see if it helps.